# HttpClient GetAsync Failure when ARM CPU is Selected

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi, arm, windows-10-iot-core

While trying to call a Rest Service, I keep getting the following error when the CPU configuration is set to ARM

> **An error occurred while sending the request**. The text associated with this error code could not be found.The server name or address could not be resolved

Switching to **Any CPU** or **x86** for example, and the call succeeds.

A sample of what the code might look like:

```
System.Uri uri = new Uri("http://servername/__/__.svc/ID/123");

using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
       {
         try
            {
              var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

              if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //handle success
                }
                else
                {
                    //handle failure   
                }
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException exc)
            {
                throw new HttpRequestException();
            }
        }
```

How to interpret this observation to solve the problem?

**Note**: App Private Networks (Client & Server) under Capabilities in the Package.appxmanifest is enabled. Calling a service without checking this capability used to cause the same error.

**Update with StackTrace**

> at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.d__86.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.d__58.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at ProjectName.Views.MainPage.d__4.MoveNext()

Comment: The networking capability is also selected?

Comment: @Quincy, the "Private Networks (Client & Server)" capability is checked.

Comment: I think there is another capability for networking/internet in general

Comment: @Quincy, right "Internet (Client)" capability ,and this one is checked by default.

Comment: @Quincy, there is also "Internet (Clien & Servert)", I will check it and try to call the service again.

Comment: Sounds like it's not a project problem but a device problem.  What is the system time for the device your deploying to?  It needs to be set to the proper time for HTTPS to work.

Comment: @Quincy, interesting, the pi system time is different, it is 8:00 AM while my Eastern time is 11.

Comment: @Quincy, I fixed the system time and restarted the device but unfortunately, I get the same error. Still, that was a very good point.

Comment: Can you do anything on the device to reach the internet?  I'd try to see what error code the network call is failing with.  Eg is it a 404 ?  I like to use the tool "Fiddler" to investigate all network traffic

Comment: @Quincy Windows 10 IoT doesn't have a browser but a Command Line; however, under DeviceInfo-> Status, it states "Local and Internet access." Pinging google etc failed (firewall issue maybe), but when I pinged the server ip where the service is hosted, I got a reply back.

Comment: Yeah it's just a ping is a different protocol than a HTTP call I think.  You could use Linux commands maybe?  I think something is wrong with configuration of device not your code.

Comment: Look into what the error is via fiddler and try to fix google.com

Comment: @Quincy regarding the configurations, I have access to the Device Portal https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/deviceportal

Comment: @Quincy I also used Fiddler to follow the request issued through a browser, and the result is a success 200 code.

Comment: @Quincy Thank you for your efforts. My supervisor got involved, and it turned out that the pi device cannot resolve the server name, so using the IP address instead resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Story short, using the server IP address instead of the host/server name, solved the problem. Otherwise, resolving the name might require editing the hosts file as described in [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/33081).